# How to make single digits?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
function SingleDigits(num) {

function makeDigits(num) {
    let value = 1 
    let arr = String(num) 
    for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
      value = value * Number(arr[i]) 
    }
      return value;
}
value += "";
while(1>=value.length){
  let result = 1;
  result = result 
}
```

I'm going to do it until I make a single digit..

```
num = 786

7 * 8 * 6 -> 336
3 * 3 * 6 -> 54
5 * 4 -> 20
2 * 0 -> 0
```

like that.. how can i setting ?? or , my direction is right ?

Comment: _"my direction is right ?"_ - That would be a "no", because your script doesn't work. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then add a [mcve], explain the problems you have with your code (preferable with sample in- and output) and add any error messages you see in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion to keep on going until the total equals 0.

eg.

```js
function digits(num) {
  const nums = num.toString().
    split('').map(Number);
  const total = nums.reduce(
    (a,v) => a * v);
  console.log(
    nums.join(' * ') + 
    " => " + total);
  if (total > 9)
    digits(total);
}


digits(786);
```

Comment: The end result of the function doesn't have to be 0. It could be any single digit number. That means whenever the multiplication results becomes less than 10 we should return that result.

Comment: @sabbir.alam  Good point, altered the condition.

Comment: @Keith Ohhh i didnt think recursion hahha;; thanks to your favor. you gave me a idea, i will study :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you have to use string here. You can do the following,

```js
function SingleDigits(num) {
   
    if(num <= 9) {
      return num;
    }
    let res = 1;
    while(num) {
      res = res * (num % 10);
      num = parseInt(num / 10);
    }
    
    if(res <= 9) {
      return res;
    }
  return SingleDigits(res);
}

console.log(SingleDigits(786));
```

Comment: actually, string can count 'length', so i thought like that.. your code is so interesting.. without num's length..

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion. The function can be pretty simple using a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to calculate the products.

```js
const singleDigit = num => {
  const nums = [...`${num}`];
  const product = nums.reduce( (acc, val) => acc * +val, 1);
  console.log(`${nums.join(" * ")} -> ${product}`);
  return product <= 9 ? product : singleDigit(product);
}

console.log(singleDigit(4328));
```

Comment: ohh reducer.. it's interesting solution! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You Should use recursive strategy.

```js
function SingleDigits(num) {
  if (parseInt(num / 10) > 0) {
    let t = 1;
    while (num > 0) {
      t *= num % 10;
      num = parseInt(num / 10);
    }
    console.log(t);
    SingleDigits(t);

  }
}
SingleDigits(786);
```

Comment: YES! I willl! i agree